# java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptionn exception in using float action button?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am just new to android, creating some app samples using two libraries. First library is [This Library](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager)
And second is [this](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)
and this is xml i'm using,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    app:primaryColor="#009688"
    app:accentColor="#ffc400"
    app:hasIcons="true" />

<com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.MaterialViewPager
    android:id="@+id/materialviewpager_pagerTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:viewpager_pagerTitleStrip="@layout/material_view_pager_pagertitlestrip_standard"
    app:viewpager_logoMarginTop="100dp"
    app:viewpager_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:viewpager_headerHeight="250dp"
    app:viewpager_headerAlpha="1.6"
    app:viewpager_hideLogoWithFade="true"
    app:viewpager_hideToolbarAndTitle="false"
    app:viewpager_enableToolbarElevation="true"
    app:viewpager_parallaxHeaderFactor="1.5"
    app:viewpager_headerAdditionalHeight="30dp"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <floatbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
            fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">

            <floatbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="Add note"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>
        </floatbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

    </FrameLayout>
    </com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.MaterialViewPager>


<include layout="@layout/drawer" />
```

I imported both of these libraries finely i tried to use this frameLayout outside from viewpager.If i run the viewpager library, its working fine.

```
FloatingActionButton actionC = new FloatingActionButton(getBaseContext());
    actionC.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_clipped);
    actionC.setTitle("Add note");
    actionC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    final FloatingActionButton actionA = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.action_a);
    actionA.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_loaction);
    actionA.setTitle("Make life Event");

    floatingActionsMenu = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions);

    floatingActionsMenu.addButton(actionC);


    floatingActionsMenu.setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener(new FloatingActionsMenu.OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuExpanded() {
            //Toast.makeText(Launcher.this, "Fdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8cffffff"));

        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuCollapsed() {
            //frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

        }
    });
```

This is floating actionbuttton's code that is copied from its library page.
My inflating a cardview layout on recyclerview.
Please help me in sorting this issue,or tell me any other library that can be used with this library?

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "floatbutton.FloatingActionsMenu" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/algonation.com.spm-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/algonation.com.spm-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) at algonation.com.spm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
```

Comment: can you please paste your log too?

Comment: That package in the xml looks a bit strange. floatbutton.FloatingActionsMenu? Shouldn't it be com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton?

Comment: would you explain? what i am doing wrong? @PedroOliveira

Comment: I posted log @GabriellaAngelova

Comment: Change that package on your xml to com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

Comment: you should change the class name `floatbutton.FloatingActionsMenu` to your class name from your project

Answer (score 0):

```
Didn't find class "floatbutton.FloatingActionsMenu"
```

It happens because in your layout your are using the wrong name. The right package is `com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton` instead of `floatbutton.FloatingActionsMenu`

Change

```
 <floatbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

in

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```